# Where to use if(obj == null) When writing API?

Tags: c#

I am always confused about when to use `if (sth == null)`. Design of delegate in C# is like this:

```
//Declaration:
private delegate void OnSthHappened();

//In some place, do:
OnSthHappened += SthHappendCallback;

//When use delegate:
if(OnSthHappened != null)
OnSthHappened();
```

I really think of judging it is null everytime when use `OnSthHappened` is unnecessary. I know that in compiler, delegate will become a class to handle the callback. Then why the C# compiler doesn't do the other way like:

```
//Use the delegate directly:
OnSthHappened();

//In the created-by-compiler class, do the judgement:
//object: instance object, Intptr method: a method pointer
if(method != 0x00) //Null, hide the judgement here
{
   Invoke(object, method);
}
```

I just gave a scene of where to judge null, this is giving me hard choices everytime when I try to write API, to do `==null` in caller or called functions? Does anyone could give me some style about where to use `==null` judgement?

Comment: Easy. Use it when the instance can be `null` when you need to use it. If it never can be `null`, then the check is redundant or you have a bug in your code.

Comment: And it is a good style to hide the delegate in a call function anyway that does the check. Look at the patterns for events. YOur naming is off and you ignore the defined patterns then you claim it is inconvenient. Yes, happens - because YOU ignore the standards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know that in compiler, delegate will become a class to handle the callback

[`Delegate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (more precise, [`MulticastDelegate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.multicastdelegate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), because in fact we work with multicast delegates) **is** a class already. The `delegate` keyword is just a way to declare a `MulticastDelegate`-derived type.

> Where to use if(obj == null) When writing API?

Shortly, check for `null`:

- in public or protected contacts, if the particular method parameter or return value must not be `null`. If it is null, throw an exception;
- in public, protected or private contracts, when value the value *could be* null, and you can handle that.

  ```
  public void Method1(Action action)
  {
      Contact.Requires<ArgumentNullException>(action != null);
  }

  public object Method2()
  {
       Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<object>() != null);

       // code here
   }

   public void Method2(Action action == null)
   {
       if (action != null)
          action();
   }
  ```

Do not check for `null`:

- in private contacts, when value must not be null.

  ```
  private void Method3()
  {
       var result = Method2();
       // In case of result == null, NRE is a best option here.
       Console.WriteLine(result.ToString().Length);
  }
  ```

**UPD**.

> why use different strategies between private and public methods? What is the benefit?

Public or protected surface is unpredictable.
You can't guarantee, that user of your class will provide, for example, valid parameter values. That's why you must check them - this is the way to tell the user, that something is wrong in **his** code. By delivering understandable exception, you can tell, what is wrong **exactly**. Note, that user hasn't access to your code, and `ArgumentNullException` on your method call is much more cleaner, that `NullReferenceException` inside of your method.

On the other hand, your release code should be clean from extra checks.
If you'll return `null` from any private method, and then try to access a member of that `null` value, you'll get `NRE` during debugging or testing. Then you have to fix error in **your** code and forget it. If you have fixed the error, there's no reason to keep the `null`-checking alive. This all doesn't avoid `Debug.Assert`/`Contract.Assert` or similar. But: a) those thing should live in debug version of your code; b) they must not be after every line of code, because this reduces code readability; c) often it is enough to catch an exception in debugger/unit test result.

Comment: Thanks, Dennis. I would like to ask why use different strategies between private and public methods? What is the benefit?